Can I avoid explicitly specifying compiler flags to get a well-optimized build?
Suppose I have a CMake project which produces a CPU-intensive application.
When I build binaries for execution on a given machine, or for performance benchmarking, I would like them to be maximally, or at least heavily, optimized for speed. Of course, some optimizations are trade-offs, which don't always improve performance, but I mean optimizations which are considered "normally good enough" to apply universally, i.e. to apply to a program without having profiled it; for example, for GCC these would be flags like -O3 -march=native and maybe others.
Now, as I browse the CMake documentation, I don't quite find a guarantee that anything like this will be done for me, if I use the Release build type.
I could, of course, set the CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_RELEASE variable, which in my specific case would be CMAKE_CPP_FLAGS_RELEASE. But - I would then need to:

Determine what platform I'm targeting
Determine features of the processor I'm targeting
Determine the compiler I'm using and which version of said compiler

and based on that - and knowledge of which compilers offer what kind of optimizations and how to enable them - I could set those flags, e.g. in an auxiliary module.
But - none of these settings is specific to my project and the program I'm compiling. I wonder why CMake doesn't do this for us...
Anyway, if we cannot leave things to CMake's care - what is a general(ish), idiomatic, hopefully widely-used approach to enable "full" optimizations in CMake, for many compilers and across multiple platforms?

All major compilers support the -O flag and the trailing number. Even MSVC (but only up to -O2). On a different note, you should use target_compile_options rather than setting variables.

Why doesn't CMake offer to do this for me? It is hard to answer why something does not exists. It does not exists because it was not done. You can do your own target Machine, implement CMAKE_CPP_FLAGS_MACHINE for all compilers that cmake supports and make a pull request to merge it upstream. the Release is what it is, and it is https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AKitware%2FCMake%20_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT&type=code Bottom line, your specific requirements or expectations do not match what cmake writers had in mind and implemented. So what now? It is not cmake fault, it tries it's best.

@KamilCuk: Removed that rhetorical question.

@Someprogrammerdude: (1.) MSVC doesn't support -O; it uses /W and I doubt it means exactly the same thing. (2.) "All major" = "Not all"... (3.) there are other optimization flags.

@einpoklum /Wn is for warnings. You are right though that MSVC  faults Unix style -On it insists on /O2,  /Oi (for inline code generation) and /Ot (favour speed). The MS IDE generated command line is hilarious with many repeated options in a complex build.

@MartinBrown: Yes, sorry, you're absolutely right.

-march=native is precisely what you don't want if building binaries for binary distribution.  I think you picked a poor example.

Short response:  no.   The meaning of "well-optimized build" depends (in general) on requirements of the program/system being built.   It might mean "as measurably fast as possible when built with  on ".  Or it might mean "smallest size executable when ....  ".   Even if either of those meanings make sense, the meaning of "well-optimized build" will depend on what the program does (e.g. numerical calculations, display, etc) and sometimes unstated opinions of customers or developers of what is important .....

@Peter: If we were to accept this view, then - why even have build types like MinSizeRel? You're claiming we should be 'dogmatically ignorant' about optimization options. I don't buy this.

@NateEldredge: You are right, actually, and that leads me to an idea I might pitch to KitWare.

@einpoklum Many MSVC options can be used with a dash instead of a slash, -O being one of them. Using  -O2 works fine.

@einpoklum  I'm not suggesting being "dogmatically ignorant".   I'm saying there is more to picking a "well-optimized build" than you imply.  Things like MinSizeRel pick a set of optimisation settings based on compiler documentation, not on any assessment of how well/optimally those settings perform or work together in practice. That requires performance benchmarking (non-trivial in general, often non-trivial even in specific use cases) to identify what is optimal - for each toolchain (and, possibly, version).  Such benchmarking is well beyond the scope or intent of tools like cmake.


Why doesn't CMake offer to do this for me?

Well, CMake can't do this for you. Nobody can, in general.
The optimal build flags can change with compiler updates, hardware updates, and simple code changes.
The only way to find the optimal flags is to run automated performance benchmarks of your own real code, in a clean lab environment, using every hardware platform, compiler revision, and combination of flags you can think of. That's not really within the remit of a build configuration tool.
If you're actually going to be satisfied with  -O3 -march=native (or the equivalent for other platforms), then that's both fairly easy to do and, potentially, a long way from maximal optimization.

There's another, probably equivalent way of looking at this.
Everybody thinks that the level of optimization they need is a reasonable default that should be built into the tooling, and that anyone who needs more specific flags is an exotic edge case.
That doesn't mean that any two of a given sample will actually agree on what this reasonable default is. If it were easy, there wouldn't be so many flags in the first place.

"The optimal build flags can change with compiler updates" <- they can change, but they rarely do; plus, CMake is aware of changes to compiler behavior/command-line interface as versions increase, at least to some extent. "hardware updates" <- again, CMake knows what the target hardware is. Naturally, if the hardware is newer than CMake then it can only rely on the compier. "and simple code changes" <- No code changes. So, can you give a concrete example for the claim of not-being-able-to-choose a maximal-optimization default?

I didn't mean the flags that exist change often. I meant which combination gives the best result for some particular code and hardware changes. And CMake can't know that without profiling your particular code on your exact hardware.

Examples include: improved auto-vectorization being usually better, except when it causes hotspots in vector units on an overclocked machine.

Improved inlining being usually better except where it blows out the icache

Ok, but, IIANM, -O3 does involve auto-vectorization. So, let's say we apply all "assumed to be usually better" optimizations - using the same criterion as compilers seem to.

Right, and your argument is that's close enough to optimal optimization for you, and mine is that is isn't for everyone.

But I agree that a cross-platform "normally good enough" level of optimization should be achievable. I'm just not sure that's exactly what you asked for.

Tweaked the question's phrasing following our exchange.
